# Is it possible to use Java functional interface implementation (such as the Supplier) as a MethodSource in Junit 5?

Tags: java, junit5, functional-interface

Running integration tests I have their arguments stored as jsons inside of diffrent files. Those files store diffrent test cases which are then tested in diffrent methods.

I wonder if it possible to create a generic read file method such as this one:

```
  static Stream<Arguments> argumentsOf(String fileName) {
    Path argumentsFilePath = Paths.get(ARGUMENTS_FILES_DIRECTORY + fileName);
    //read and return arguments stored in a file 
  }
```

Together with a functional interface like this one:

```
     static Supplier<Stream<Arguments>> anExampleArgument =
      () -> argumentsOf("some_test_case_argument.json");
```

So I can do something like this:

```
  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("anExampleArgument.get")
  void test1(String exampleArgument) {
  //...
  }
```

I couldn't find any information regarding this scenario. The example code seen above results in

```
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: Could not find factory method [anExampleArgument.get] in class [com.company.ExampleIntegrationTest]
```

Comment: Seems like https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests is a better suited tool for your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, at the moment what you describe does not seem to be possible.

The docs of [MethodSource](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-MethodSource) are not very clear on this, but looking at [its JavaDoc](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/junit-jupiter-params/src/main/java/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/MethodSource.java) may provide some insight:

> Factory methods in external classes must be referenced by *fully qualified method name* — for example, `com.example.StringsProviders#blankStrings`.

The code that throws the exception that you're seeing is [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/junit-jupiter-params/src/main/java/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/MethodArgumentsProvider.java#L81):

```java
private Method getMethod(Class<?> clazz, String methodName) {
    return ReflectionUtils.findMethod(clazz, methodName).orElseThrow(() -> new JUnitException(
    format("Could not find factory method [%s] in class [%s]", methodName, clazz.getName())));
}
```

Sadly, their [ReflectionUtils](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/junit-platform-commons/src/main/java/org/junit/platform/commons/util/ReflectionUtils.java) class does not seem to include any functionality for evaluating additional calls after a method, so it treats your String as a fully qualified method name.

Perhaps you'd benefit from creating your own `ArgumentsProvider` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59264053/8027026)?

As a commenter points out, perhaps [Dynamic Tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests) might also work for your use case.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally you could quite easily create your own `@FileSource` annotation:

```
@Target({ ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ArgumentsSource(FileArgumentsProvider.class)
public @interface FileSource {

    String[] value() default "";

}
```

Together with an `ArgumentsProvider`:

```
public class FileArgumentsProvider implements ArgumentsProvider, AnnotationConsumer<FileSource> {

    private String[] fileNames;

    @Override
    public void accept(FileSource fileSource) {
        this.fileNames = fileSource.value();
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<? extends Arguments> provideArguments(ExtensionContext context) {
        return Arrays.stream(fileNames).map(this::readFile).map(Arguments::of);
    }

    private String readFile(String fileName) {
        return "the actual content of the file";
    }

}
```

And use it like this:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@FileSource({"test_case_1.json", "test_case_2.json", "test_case_3.json"})
void test(String fileContent) {
    // Your test code
}
```